# Why do egrep and grep behave differently although they are the same binary?

Tags: bash, grep, history

```
$ ls -l /bin/*grep
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4 2010-06-09 02:56 /bin/egrep -> grep
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4 2010-06-09 02:56 /bin/fgrep -> grep
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 85060 2007-01-23 02:00 /bin/grep

$ echo 'hello' | grep -q 'l{2}' && echo YES || echo NO
NO

$ echo 'hello' | egrep -q 'l{2}' && echo YES || echo NO
YES
```

In my system, `egrep` is a symbolic link to `grep`, but they behave differently. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` will check its invocation by looking at `argv[0]`.

Here's a short program to demonstrate:

```
> cat someprogram.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Shall behave as " << argv[0] << "." << std::endl;
}
```

Build:

```
> make someprogram
g++ someprogram.cpp   -o someprogram
```

Make a symbolic link:

```
> ln -s someprogram some_other_program
```

Run one:

```
> ./someprogram
Shall behave as ./someprogram.
```

Run two:

```
> ./some_other_program 
Shall behave as ./some_other_program.
```

[Gnu `grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) is [free](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.html) and open source software, so you are free to examine [the source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/).

Answer (score 2):

Because the executable checks the value of `argv[0]` and adjusts its behavior accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Because POSIX says that `egrep` is equivalent to [`grep -E`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) and not plain `grep`, and `fgrep` is equivalent to `grep -F` and not plain `grep`.  If you want `grep` to behave the same as `egrep`, use `grep -E`, and so on.  There is also the issue of about 40 years of precedent.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is identical apart from the regex engine; it makes sense to share the code, either by creating a library (a more common approach these days) or by using a single binary which examines its name (`argv[0]`) to determine which behavior is requested.  (A third possibility is to have a single name and use options to select different behaviors, of course.  This is what commands like `git` and `tar` do; a single command is the "interface" but you get vastly different behaviors by specifying different actions.)

The reason there are distinct commands is a long legacy, going back to the early days of Unix.  Plain old `grep` was one of the earliest implementations of regular expressions, and as the developers' understanding of this particular problem domain improved, new tools with new capabilities evolved.  For reasons of backwards compatibility, these new features could not simply be integrated to `grep` (this would have changed its behavior) so the new commands had new names.  By the time POSIX got around to standardizing things, the division of labor between `grep`,  `egrep` and `fgrep` was firmly established, although in hindsight, you could argue that at least one of them is redundant.